# Joomla 3.x how to delete the data using an object

Tags: joomla

In joomla 3.x implemented delete the data from database using object
this my code not working

```html
function deleteJob()
{   
 $id = $_REQUEST['id_ud'];
 $object = new stdClass();
    $object->id = $id;
    $resultd =JFactory::getDbo()->deleteObject('#___institute_post_job',$object, 'id');
 }
if(isset($_POST['inidelete_job'])) {
 deleteJob();
 }
```

please help me?

Comment: Dont use `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`. see this: https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Answer (score 1):

There is No method for "deleteObject" . if you want to delete operation , you have write query and execute.

There is no object delete just like insertObject,updateObject,...

refer last example for delete:
https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

JFactory::getDBo() basically call JDatabaseDriver,you can use following methods.
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html